# How to sort any vector by value?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

How to sort a vector by absolute value in c++?

suppose a vector {-10, 12, -20, -8, 15}

output should be {-8, -10, 12, 15, -20}

Comment: Can you clarify: do you mean sort by *absolute* value?  In fact, I don't see how the original vector can be sorted in *any* way to provide that output.

Comment: and what happened to the `1` in the `vector`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you want to sort the vector by absolute value.
You can sort a vector with [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) in any way you want by passing a lambda to it.
The absolute value of an integer can be calulated using [`std::abs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs).

```cpp
std::sort(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec),
          [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){
              return std::abs(lhs) < std::abs(rhs);
          });
```